# Nested ASP validation

Tags: validation, asp-classic, if-statement

I have a form asking for four types of donations. The user must choose one of four donations. Also, depending on which one they choose, they are required to fill in the adjacent field (the amount).

If A1 is filled in B1 must be filled in
If A2 is filled in B2 must be filled in
If A3 is filled in B3 must be filled in
If A4 is filled in B4 must be filled in

... but at least one of the A's must be filled in.

Comment: what is the question? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), do you want to validate form input fields, are you validating them in the client side or server side?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're after ASP validation (i.e. after the post) you could do something like this:

```
dim A1 : A1 = trim(request.form("A1"))
dim A2 : A2 = trim(request.form("A2"))
dim A3 : A3 = trim(request.form("A3"))
dim A4 : A4 = trim(request.form("A4"))

dim B1 : A1 = trim(request.form("B1"))
dim B2 : B2 = trim(request.form("B2"))
dim B3 : B3 = trim(request.form("B3"))
dim B4 : B4 = trim(request.form("B4"))

dim ValidationError : ValidationError = ""

if A1 <> "on" and A2 <> "on" and A3 <> "on" and A4 <> "on" then
    ValidationError = "Please select at least one option"
else
    if A1 = "on" and B1 = "" then ValidationError = "You selected A1, please complete the amount"
    if A2 = "on" and B2 = "" then ValidationError = "You selected A2, please complete the amount"
    if A3 = "on" and B3 = "" then ValidationError = "You selected A3, please complete the amount"
    if A4 = "on" and B4 = "" then ValidationError = "You selected A4, please complete the amount"
end if

if ValidationError <> "" then
    response.write(ValidationError)
else
    '#### All OK
end if
```

But stuff like this is often slicker with javascript (client side - pre-post) validation.

Comment: @RicoSuave Well spotted, Dims where indeed in full vb, changed to vba